# PrimeNG Table - How to clear a text filter in code and a p-table

Tags: angular, primeng, p-table

I have been trying to figure this out for over a week now. I can't seem to be able to clear my filters without breaking them. I need a button that clears all the filters on my screen so the user does not have to do them one by one.

Here is my stackblitz link for the sample code. Does anyone know how to make this work? I am starting to think there is a bug in the new PrimeNG Table filter process.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clear-filters?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `p-table` reference variable **`#mydt`** to your clear function like following

**`app.component.html`**

```
<button pButton label="Clear Filters"  class="p-button-outlined" icon="pi pi-filter-slash" (click)="clear(mydt)"></button>
```

and use `table.clear()` method

**`app.component.ts`**

```
clear(table: Table) {      
   table.clear();
}
```

I have updated your **`stackblitz`** :

**https://stackblitz.com/edit/clear-filters-6jxnp3?file=src/app/app.component.ts**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, However this solution does not work either. If you go to your stackblitz link and select Set Filters and then select Clear Filters and then try to filter by a name you will see that the name filter does not work and also country filter is broken as well.